# Linux Mint 21.1 unresponsive after lid closed for too long

Tags: linux-mint

I recently upgraded to Mint 21.1 and if I close the lid and leave it shut for more than about 60 seconds, it goes to sleep and won't respond to key strokes or tapping the touch pad. I have to restart the computer. How do I fix this? Is it fixable without updates?

Comment: Have you tried pressing the power button? (don't press it for a long time, just press it like any other key). I remember having this issue and pressing the power button worked.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon yes. That is what works but then all of my programs are closed and I have to restart everything. But I'm trying to see if there is another way to wake up without having to restart the system.